# Iterate through a list of objects and find the one with the highest price and set it to Active and disable all others

Tags: c#, linq, for-loop

I have a list of products with a Price property.

I need to iterate through the list of products and set the one with the highest price to Enabled = true. The trick is that I need to make the rest of the products that aren't the MAX to Enabled = false.

**Here is my current code, but I feel terrible running the foreach loop to set all others to Enabled = false every single time. There has to be a better way:**

```
decimal maxPrice = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < products.Count; i++)
{
    Product product = products[i];

    if (product.Price > maxPrice)
    {
        maxPrice = product.Price;
        product.Enabled = true;

        // Set all others to Disabled
        foreach (Product other in products.Where(p => p.Id != product.Id))
        {
            other.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you want to handle a scenario where you have, say, a list of 100 products, and three of them have the exact same max value? Set all of them to be enabled, or just the first one? Something else?

Comment: I would just take the first and only enable that one. Can you tweak your function based on that?

Comment: I added an answer bellow that only sets the first item to be enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the products have `Enabled` property with `false` value by default, then just save the index of max value in your `for`:

```
int index=0;
for (int i = 1; i < products.Count; i++)
{
    if (products[i].Price > products[index].Price)
        index=i;
}
products[index].Enabled = true;
```

### Update:

In case you have some elements with `true` value before execute your `for`, then you could add an `else` statement to set to `false` those elements you already know that aren't the maximum. But you can jump some items that were partial max and had `true` value when you start the `for`.
An easy way is doing this:

```
int index=0;
for (int i = 1; i < products.Count; i++)
{
    if (products[i].Price > products[index].Price)
    {
        products[index].Enabled=false; //in case a partial max had true value before starting to iterate 
        index=i;   
    }
    else
    {
       products[i].Enabled=false;
    }
}
products[index].Enabled = true;
```

Comment: and if they're not already false, you can set them to false in the for loop before the test

Comment: Works great, but please confirm that there is a type in the if statement. 'product' should be 'products' right?

Comment: @octavioccl Also, can you show me how I would set to false just to be safe like user3486184 mentioned.

Comment: The first one is the max value by default, that's why I start the cycle in index=1. In case of other element is greater then index variable is updated.

Answer (score 1):

I made a dummy class with the following properties to try solve this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}
```

And created the list like so:

```
var list = new List<Foo>();
list.Add(new Foo(){ Name = "Thing 1", Value = 1});
list.Add(new Foo(){ Name = "Thing 2", Value = 3});
list.Add(new Foo(){ Name = "Thing 3", Value = 5});
list.Add(new Foo(){ Name = "Thing 4", Value = 2});
list.Add(new Foo(){ Name = "Thing 5", Value = 4});
```

You can start by setting all Products in the list to have their Enabled value set to false:

```
list.ForEach(l => l.Enabled = false);
```

You can then reorder them in descending order, so from highest value to lowest value:

```
list = list.OrderByDescending(l => l.Value).ToList();
```

Or if you want to sort the list in-place in descending order, you can do this:

```
list.Sort((a, b) => b.Value.CompareTo(a.Value));
```

Finally you can set the first item to have its Enabled property set to true:

```
list.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Enabled = true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two simple foreach loops ought to do it.

```
decimal maxPrice = 0

foreach (product p in products)
{
    if (p.Price > maxPrice)
        maxPrice = p.Price;
}

foreach (product p in products)
{
    if (p.Price == maxPrice)
        p.Enabled = true;
    else
        p.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but the problem with this is that I don't like comparing the price at the end. Id rather use an Id or something unique assuming there can be more than one with the highest price. In that case I would like to take the first of the two.